# Access columns of a data frame within a list of data frames in python

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe

Suppose I have a list with different dataframes:

pseudo-code:

```
list = [df1, df2]
```

I want to do the following:

pseudo-code II:

```
list.df1.column1
```

that is, I want to look at my list, choose the dataframe I want, and in this dataframe I want to look at a specific column -- either by its name or by its numerical position.

I am a new user of python and I found no source that could help me.

Answer (score 0):

List do not have . access , you may

```
list = [df1, df2]
list[0].column1
```

---

Also I recommend using dict store your dfs

```
d={'df1':df1,'df2':df2}
d['df1'].column1
```

Comment: because my list feature many df's, I found that in practice to add the column name is not straightforward. So, I decided to first get the column names from each dataframe. But the problem is that this line of code `list[0].column1' the last piece is not a string. So, my question is how I could get my column names from each df, and then pass those into the line of code you suggested.